# Curves and straight lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a question that states there is a curve with an equation of $x^2+y^2 +12x=64$ and a straight line with equation of $y=mx+10$ and states the line crosses the curve at two distinct points, therefore I have to show that $(20m+12)^2-144(m^2+1)>0$ and then to find the possible values of $m$. I’ve tried rearranging the two equations but I can’t work out how to get it into the form they are asking for! Is there an easier way of answering this question!?!?! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> I have a question that states there is a curve with an equation of $x^2 +y^2 +12x =64$ and a straight line with equation of $y=mx+10$

**Hint**

Substitution of $y=mx+10$ into $x^2 +y^2 +12x =64$ gives you a quadratic equation in the variable $x$, rewrite in standard form $ax^2+bx+c=0$. It has two distinct solutions if its discriminant $D=b^2-4ac$ is strictly positive; verify that this exactly gives what you want:

> therefore I have to show that $(20m+12)^2-144(m^2+1)>0 $

Answer (score 0):

we have: $$y=mx+10$$ $$y^2=m^2x^2+20mx+100$$

sub  $y^2=m^2x^2+20mx+100$ into $x^2+y^2+12x=64$ we have 
$$x^2+m^2x^2+20mx+100+12x=64$$

then we have to group terms into $$(1+m^2)x^2+(20m+12)x+34=0$$
last, we apply $b^2-4ac$ and turn into the desired form $(20m+12)^2−144(m^2+1)>0$